# Kendo template send data

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

What I want is simple but I don't know if it's possible.

I have a Kendo Mobile ListView as below:

```
e.view.element.find("#list-serviceorders").kendoMobileListView({
    dataSource: ds,
    pullToRefresh: true,
    template: $("#list-serviceorders-template").html()
});
```

And I want to send to the template some values to access on it. My *view* with the template is this:

```
<div data-role="view" data-before-show="GAPCP.viewBeforeShow" id="serviceorders" data-layout="main-item-list">
    <ul id="list-serviceorders"></ul>
</div>

<script id="list-serviceorders-template" type="text/x-kendo-template" data-teste="teste">
    <a href="views/entries.html?id=#: CodOs #">OS: #: CodOs #<br />
    #: parameter.Divi1 #: #: CodDivi1 #/#: parameter.Divi2 #: #: CodDivi2 #</a>
</script>
```

Where you can read `parameter.Divi1` and `parameter.Divi2` are the places where I want to display those values. They're are not in the Data Source like the others values.

I don't want to create global variable 'cause I don't want to mess with my code and I can't use a function for that purpose because those values come from the database and it will execute a query for each list item iteration.

Any suggestion of how do that?

Comment: Either is in the model or is global. I think that the question is that you can have it in the model without having it the list of values retrieved with the DataSource. Is this good enough? Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @OnaBai Yeah I got it. But, can I got it in the controller instead of the model? So if yes and if a I can sent it to the template, will resolve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I'm proposing is adding this information to the model in the controller. You can do it in [`DataSource.schema.parse`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.parse) or in [`requestEnd`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#events-requestEnd), even in a `dataBound` event if the widget accepts it.

When the data is received you iterate through the model and fills the remaining data not received from the server.

Example: Using `parse`

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url : ...
        }
    },
    schema   : {
        model: {
            CodOs   : { type: "number" },
            CodDivi1: { type: "string" },
            CodDivi2: { type: "string" }
        },
        parse: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (idx, elem) {
                // Extend original elem
                elem.parameter = {
                    Divi1: elem.CodDivi1.toUpperCase(),
                    Divi2: elem.CodDivi2.toLowerCase()
                }
            });
            return data;
        }
    }
});
```

Where I compute `parameter` inside the `parse` function and set `parameter.Divi1` to `CodDivi1` in upper-case and `parameter.Divi2` to `CodDivi2` in lowercase.

Comment: If with this method the template receives `CodOs, CodDivi1, CodDivi2, Divi1 and Divi2` (where Divi1 and Divi2 will be manipulated) your answer will satisfy the question. I'll be able to test it on monday, then I post the result. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Nice! It worked! And you don't need to pass that model object. The dataSource content is also available, I only have to use `#: parameter.Divi1 #` on the view. Thank you!